# disable click until animation is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the animation to run before allowing clicking of the next button so the animation does not go out of sync. i don't know what would be better bind / unbind or something like a while not true loop.

```
function first_horizontal_slider() {
    var $scroller = $('div#first_slider');
    var counter = 0;

    $('div#first_left_btn a').css({ 'background': 'url(img/left_arrow_bw.png) no-repeat' });
    $('div#first_right_btn a').css({ 'background': 'url(img/right_arrow.png) no-repeat' });
    $('div#first_left_btn a').click(function () {

        if (counter != 0) {
            $('div#first_right_btn a').css({ 'background': 'url(img/right_arrow.png) no-repeat' });

            $scroller.stop().animate({
                "left": "+=732px"
            }, "slow");
            counter--;

            if (counter == 0) {
                $('div#first_left_btn a').css({ 'background': 'url(img/left_arrow_bw.png) no-repeat' });
            }
        }
        return false;
    });

    $('div#first_right_btn a').click(function () {
        if (counter != 2) {
            $('div#first_left_btn a').css({ 'background': 'url(img/left_arrow.png) no-repeat' });
            $scroller.stop().animate({
                "left": "-=732px"
            }, "slow");
            counter++;

            if (counter == 2) {
                $('div#first_right_btn a').css({ 'background': 'url(img/right_arrow_bw.png) no-repeat' });
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used a `button` or `input type="button"` then you would be able to set `.disabled` to `true` before the animation, and back to `false` after.

Answer (score 0):

on callback function of animate you can set button to enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the button at the start of the animation and have a callback in the `complete` method of the animation to enable the button

```
 //before animation starts
disableButton()

$scroller.stop().animate({
            "left":"+=732px"
        },"slow", 'swing', enableButton); //added default easing

function enableButton() {
   $('#thebutton').removeAttr('disabled');
}

function disableButton() {
   $('#thebutton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [jQuery end](http://api.jquery.com/end/) or check via [jQuery animated](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/)